# SL4A python не работают нотификации

Tags: android, python, qpython

Не работают нотификации из кода *python*

Вызывается так:

```
from androidhelper import Android

droid = Android()

droid.notify( "test notification", "this is test notification" )
```

Возвращает следующее:

```
Result( id=1, result=None, error=None )
```

Но в панели нотификаций пусто.

python на андроиде версии 2.7.2 из пакета *qpython*. *SL4A* версии *r6*.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в коде. Стоит включить уведомления в настройках телефона.

У меня *Samsung*, поэтому путь такой `Уведомления > QPython 3L > test notification` (или название, которое вы написали в коде).

Я не понимаю, почему оно отключено, ведь раньше всё работало.